# How focus off on a toggle button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem by handling focus on/off on a toggle button. If I click on the button the focus goes on and also appear the container, so it works good. If I re-click on the button the container disappear but the focus still remain with focus on! The only solution is click outside the button to focus off and this is very bad. So I would like: focus visible when the container appear (click on button) and focus off when the container disappear (re-click on button). How can I fix it?
here fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/802/ 
as you can see when re-click the button, the container disappear but blue color (focus on) remain, so the button doesn't come back to the original color in automatic.

css:

```
.ini{
color: red;
border: 2px solid #0000FF;
}
.ini:hover, .ini:focus{
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}
```

js:

```
  $("#chi").hide();
  $("#hs1").click(function(){
      if($('#chi').is(':hidden')){
      $("#chi").toggle(500);}
      else{$("#chi").hide(1000);}
  });
```

html:

```
<a class="btn btn-default ini" id="hs1" href="#" role="button">TEST</a>
<div class="container" id="chi">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-centered">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                     <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Test</h2><h5>Test</h5></div>
                     <div class="panel-body">
                       <p>Test</p>
                       </div>
               </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle.

Comment: You could just set outline: 0; on the .ini:focus  css class if you don't want the focus to be visible.

Comment: I want focus visible when the container appear (click on button) and focus off when the container disappear (re-click on button)

Comment: here fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yryq75jy/
as you can see when you re-click the button, the container disappear but blue color (focus on) remain, so the button doesn't come back to the original color in automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyzwvybe/8/)

**CSS :**

```
.ini:hover {
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);  
}

.active {
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);  
}
```

**JS :**

```
$("#chi").hide();
  $("#hs1").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
            if($('#chi').is(':hidden')){
      $("#chi").toggle(500);}
      else{$("#chi").hide(1000);}
  });
```

Comment: Not work with bootstrap3 :(
https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/802/

Comment: That's because "active" is a name of a generic class in Bootstrap, you have to change the name, here's a working example :  https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/804/

Comment: check the border color and text color because they doesn't return to the original color when re-click

Comment: I added a line in the javascript "blur" to avoid keeping the focus when you click : https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/810/

Comment: Now works pretty well with single button. Last problem: if I have two button and each one comand a appear/disappear container? If I implement your code the focus not work good. Infact when I click one button1 it focus but if I click also the other button2 the focus don't disappear on the button1 and the final result is two focus and this is bad.

Comment: Yes you have to adapt name of the class and also the javascript by using $(this) to refer to the current element you're clicking.

Comment: here the example: https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/813/
I don't understand where I mistake :/

Comment: Done, now works!
https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/819/